# Using Sphinx4.0 to build a speech recog. Android application

Tags: android, eclipse, forceclose, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I have been creating a java application for speech recognition using Sphinx4 in eclipse IDE and it worked out good! But now, i have an idea of turning the project to work on android platform.

The code came out well for the sphinx4 demo speech recog. program in Android, But it crashes when i try to run it on a device! saying it has "Stopped Unexpectedly!" (Force closed)

From my Survey in the internet, i've heard that Sphinx configures microphone in a way thats not compatible with dalvik.

SO is there any way i can get these two things to work together?? Like configure mic in the dalvik device and use sphinx just to process the input??

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx4 is not designed for mobile applications. Use pocketsphinx instead:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

You should use [eyes-free](http://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/) for speech-enabled Android applications.